# CSS background image color overlay

Tags: html, css, colors, background-image, overlay

This works:

```
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(100, 100, 100, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/web-101/unit-4/htmlcss1-img_coffee-bgnd.jpeg");
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
.header {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5), url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/web-101/unit-4/htmlcss1-img_coffee-bgnd.jpeg");
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Anyone have any why explanation? Why cant I just `RGBA` the image slightly with color overlay without using linear-gradient?

Please don't kill me, complete beginner.

Comment: if you use a simple color (even if it's an `RBGA` value) it will be read as a color. If you use a gradient, the output is an image. When you use a simple color, you don't need the comma between the `RGBA` value and the `url` of an image but then it will be a **fallback background** instead of an overlay - it will render below the image once loaded - that is unless you specify something else in the `background-blend-mode` property. If you use a gradient then, because the output is an image, you need the comma. Your issue is syntax. Why not use a pseudo-element for the overlay?

Comment: The flagged dupe has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Why has this post been flagged as duplicate with irrelevant question links ? Anyway, here's a sort of answer for you.

https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: Ye, i already found that myself as well, bottom of the story, there doesnt seem to be some hard answer, why its been done like that

Answer (score 0):

You use like this code:

Here id working demo: https://output.jsbin.com/voyotep

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="layer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  background:url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/web-101/unit-4/htmlcss1-img_coffee-bgnd.jpeg');
  min-height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  position: relative;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, it doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: Thank you for your demo, thats another way around this problem, of adding overlay over an image. i like your solution, since using linear-gradient, and pasting same color two times seems like ghetto solution. But it wasn't actually the question :)

Comment: Just remove `,` with space after `background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5)` like this

`.header {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5) url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/web-101/unit-4/htmlcss1-img_coffee-bgnd.jpeg");
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center center;
}`